# Путь к файлу автоматически создаваемой страницы

Tags: wordpress, файлы, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Создал страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В адресной строке написано `digitalelectronics.ru/elementor-7/` . Но такой папки в сайте нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в каком файле помещается шаблон файла, отображаемого в браузере под адресом `digitalelectronics.ru\elementor-7`?
Я начал поиск файлов, указанных (возможно, что-то не заметил - перепроверьте свежим взглядом) в [Иерархия файлов](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#page-templates-within-the-template-hierarchy)

но не нашел (см. скриншот далее ниже)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

посмотрел временный файл (нужный, искомый)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем произвел поиск файла по тексту, встречающимся в коде хрома (см. сразу выше) - `Elementor #7 - Digital Electronics`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но ничего не нашел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом узнать файл сайта, который открыт в Elementor?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Ни в каком. Содержимое генерируется на лету, никаких файлов не создаётся.

Answer (score 2):

Elementor - это плагин конструктора страниц. Это не отдельная тема. Результат работы конструктора - это набор шорткодов, которые он интерпретирует в html код. Все данные в базе.

Comment: я переформулировал вопрос

Comment: отображение страницы согласно иерархии page templates (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#page-templates-within-the-template-hierarchy)

Comment: я добавил новую инфу в вопрос.

Comment: я не акцентировал внимание на базе данных (из-за чего задал несколько лишних вопросов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177625/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-link-elementor-config-document-urls-permalink) -  1. Что за база? 2. И каким образом можно отредактировать запись в базе?