# Проблемы с редактированием Sources в Инструментах разработчика

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, инструменты-разработчика

Создал файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался редактировать файлы `http://digitalelectronics.ru/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty-child/style.css?ver=0.1.0` (удалось, см. `{` после `section`) и `http://digitalelectronics.ru/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/css/frontend-legacy.min.css?ver=3.0.7` (тоже удалось)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а главная страница `(index)` (в которой отображается логотип с техникой) не редактируется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как отредактировать файл, отображаемый в браузере (`(index)`)?

Comment: Судя по вашему предыдущему вопросу, вы пытаетесь редактировать index.php в браузере. Это невозможно.

Comment: @KAGGDesign где  вышеприведенный в браузере файл можно отредактировать?

Comment: В браузере - нигде. Php файлы надо редактировать по ftp

Comment: это локальный сайт, пути к которому я не знаю - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177084/%d0%a4%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1177625/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-link-elementor-config-document-urls-permalink

Comment: @KAGGDesign поэтому я не знаю как редактировать по ftp, так как не знаю пути к файлу

Comment: Не понимаю, как можно не знать, где размещён локальный сайт. Вы что, не сами его создавали на своём компьютере? Поищите, в конце концов, полным поиском по всем файлам папку twentytwenty-child, она у вас в вопросе упомянута.

Comment: И судя по следующему вопросу, вы уже нашли.

Comment: Начинайте читать отсюда, у вас совершенно недостаточный уровень знаний https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/wordpress